# Variable inside callback function angularjs

Tags: ajax, angularjs, callback

I try to use $scope inside a factory to stock a value but i can't.

I try also to push the value into an array, it doesn't work.

I just want to copy a callback value into a variable to return it from a factory.

This is a sample :

```
var cpy = {};
$http.get('/api/things/')
.success(function (data){
          cpy = data;
         })
        .error(function (err){

        });

console.log(cpy);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you must use promsie.   https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: @user3227295 $http already return a promise.

Comment: the console.log function fired before callback function

Comment: @user3227295 You don't need to explicitly use promise cause $http.get() already return one. This is just the workflow that wasn't good. Check my answer if you want some detail.

Answer (score 0):

That was almost what you need.

You factory should look like :

```
var getCopy = function(){
    return $http.get('/api/things/');
}
```

And in your controller you get it like this :

```
myfactory.getCopy().success(function(data){
   $scope.myscopedvar = data;
});
```

If you want some binding in your scope it'll always be done in the controller. If it's an asynchronous call, it's the responsibility of your controller to know what to do when the $http promise resolve.

Hope it helped, if you want more explanation feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Maxim, Okazari and  user3227295.

my factory look like this :

```
angular.module('feedbackApp').factory('Data', function ($http, $q, Auth) {
    $http.get('/api/things/')
    .success(function (data){
              cpy = data;
             })
            .error(function (err){

            });
                return {first : true}; 
          });
```

I just want to check if cpy was not empty to return false and return true for empty variable.

Sorry to asked the question without much precisions.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try my solution ? You should do this in your controller in the .success() method

Comment: it doesn't work, I need a factory because I have bootstrap modal to displayu a welcome message just one time, when you close it, I insert into database, then every login you will not see the welcome message.